# Spring boot initialization without @PostConstruct annotation

Tags: spring-boot, postconstruct

I developed a Spring Boot application that currently works well with `@PostConstruct` initialization.

Now, with another requirement, I added another `initApp()` in the Service class and I found that the service is initialized twice -  when called from the integrated app using `initApp()` as well as by default `postconstruct` annotated method.

I would like to initialize with `initApp()` only so I removed `postconstruct` annotated method. Doing so, the service is not initialized stand-alone (deployed on web server) but working fine with the integrated app.

Can someone help me how can I initialize the service without `postconstrct` annotation that works when deployed (as war file) on server?

Here is the pom.xml
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.study</groupId>
        <artifactId>test_component</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <start-class>com.study.TestStarter</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <assembly_build_version>2.3.523</assembly_build_version>
        <descriptorRef>${svc_install_pkg}</descriptorRef>
        <!-- Additionally, Please make sure that your JAVA_HOME is pointing to 
            1.8 when building on commandline -->
        <skip_tomcat_bundle>false</skip_tomcat_bundle>

        <tomcat_bundle>tomcat85_24.tgz</tomcat_bundle>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others -->
        <!--dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin><!-- Include if you want to make an executable jar[FAT JAR which 
                    includes all dependencies along with sprinboot loader] that you can run on 
                    commandline using java -jar NAME -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>target/hgvs-${project.version}.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you post a small example of the service and what exactly you're trying to set up?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way by myself to solve this by initializing the service in the controller class with @Postcontruct annotation.